# VBA sum variable range with some empty rows between variable range and sum

Tags: vba, excel

I did some research and got the feeling its a rather simple question..

i want  to sum a variable range: in my sheet, L25 can run to infinity, tricky part (for me), it shouldn't SUM till the last row-1 but last row -3 as there is a 'Totals' text above the place where the sum should be

[image]

so totals should be summed in L40, which in different cases can be another L row.

I think it's not that hard, but as I am a beginner, I think I make a elementary mistake. To show my effort, I managed to get this:

```
Sub Sumvariablerow
  Range("L40").Select
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-15]C:R[-3]C)"
End Sub
```

Got the feeling it should be something like this:

```
Sub Sumvariablerow
  Range("L40").Select
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(L25:L" & R - 3 & ")"
End Sub
```

found the following topics:
[How to sum values in variable range in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28990296/how-to-sum-values-in-variable-range-in-vba)

[VBA Summing a Column of Variable Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085074/vba-summing-a-column-of-variable-length)

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/584966-visual-basic-applications-sum-variable-length-column.html

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/251264-sum-formula-variable-rowcount-using-visual-basic-applications.html

thanks in advance

Comment: both solutions worked for me! thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with the below code

```
Sub test()
    Range("L" & Range("L25").End(xlDown).Row + 3).Formula = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("L25:L" & Range("L25").End(xlDown).Row))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this almost works but has a different problem: row sum is variable but it only counts (sums) the last row.. so (following the picutre) the sum according to your code is €365?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that:

```
Range("L40").Formula = "=SUM(L25:L" & 24 + Range(Range("L25"), Range("L25").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count & ")"
```

Comment: Thanks, brings me somewhere, only problem, the "Range("L40").Formula =" causes the SUM will always be in the "L40" cell if list is longer (say totals should add up in L50, its still adding up @ L40? any thoughs?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub Sumvariablerow()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("L25").End(xlDown).Row
    Cells(LastRow + 2, 12).Value = "total"
    Cells(LastRow + 3, 12).Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(L25:" & ActiveCell.Offset(Rowoffset:=-3).Address & ")"
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, same here, works but if there are less or more cells filled in L than it still places the sum in L40?

Comment: @bart1701 - Its counting number of rows in the code. Oops I've edited my code.